# Подсказка для имени участника при регистрации

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице [регистрации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup) (открывать в приватном режиме) подсказка в поле "Отображаемое имя" содержит текст *"J. Doe"*.

> [image: J.Doe]

Считаю, что этот текст следует локализовать. На текущий момент, правда, упомянутая строка отсутствует в transifex.

[Вопрос о необходимости иметь возможность перевода](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290945/339911) через transifex добавлен на MSE.

Comment: Исправил, будет доступно при следующем обновлении базы строк (неизвестно, когда). https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/108247726?key=fd2fe8600e216adb3862d722337bf049

Comment: @NickVolynkin уже можно наблюдать в действии

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В качестве перевода предлагаю использовать такой вариант:

> [Василий Пупкин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Это имя уже используется в другом [переводе](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264454?key=15b1e5eae38b3241b249b6718c3f559a):

> John Doe$br$United States

> Василий Пупкин$br$Россия

Comment: «прецедентный феномен виртуального дискурса»